# How can I correctly use a Promise on an async function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, promise

I have an asynchronous function in node that reads a text file, puts the whole thing into a string, splits the string at every new line, puts them into an array and returns one at random. Here I have implemented a new Promise function to deal with it:

```
exports.readTextFileAndReturnRandomLine = function readTextFile(file)
{
    //reads text file as string, splits on new line and inserts into array, returns random array element
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var textFile = fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) =>
        {
            if (err)
            {
                return reject(err);
            }
            else
            {
                var array = data.toString().split("\n");
                var response = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
                return resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the text file that the function is reading from:

```
Hello there, 
Howdy, 
I will remember your name, 
Thanks for telling me, 
Hi 
Noted, 
Thanks 
Well hello there 
Nice to meet you 
The pleasure is all mine, 
Nice name,
```

Now in my root node (app.js), I call the function like so:

```
intents.matches('RememberName', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        var nameEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'name');
        if (!nameEntity)
        {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Sorry, didn't catch your name. What is it?");
        } else 
        {
            next({ response: nameEntity.entity });
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        if (results.response)
        {         
            fileReader.readTextFileAndReturnRandomLine('./text/remembername.txt').then(function(value) {
                console.log(value + ", " + results.response);
            }).catch(function(reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            session.send("Ok");
        }
    }
]);
```

The problem is that the `value` and `name` variables are not being printed out to the console in the order that I have put them in. Here is my **actual** output:

```
my name is chris
, Chrisfor telling me,
my name is Chris
, Chris
my name is Chris
, Chris
my name is Chris
, Chrishere,
my name is Chris
, Chrisfor telling me,
my name is Chris
, Chrisasure is all mine,
my name is Chris
, Chris
my name is Chris
, Chris
my name is Chris
, Chrisllo there
```

And here is my **expected** output:

```
my name is Chris
Hello there, Chris
my name is Chris
Howdy, Chris
my name is Chris
Nice to meet you Chris
my name is Chris
Nice name, Chris
```

I believe it has something to do with the synchronicity of it all but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Comment: Can you try without "return" in return resolve(response); and return reject(err);

Comment: @donlys I have tried this and unfortunately it produces the same outcome :(

Comment: Can you try then clause with just then(function(value){console.log(value + ", " + name);}).catch(function(reason){console.log(reason)})

Comment: @donlys Still not working :9

Comment: Have you tried `session.send` instead of `console.log`?

Comment: @tcooc yep - I managed to find the problem and it was something so petty. Check my answer at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the character returns `'\r'` were being brought into the string from the text file. Applying the `.trim()` method to the `response` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So there is a little error in your code. The definition of promise takes 2 functions - `resolve` and `reject`.

But when you call the promise, you do a `then()` and `catch()`. You pass `resolve()` in `then()` and `reject()` in `catch()`.

So all you have to do is change the last bit of code to this:

```
var name = "Chris";
fileReader.readTextFileAndReturnRandomLine('./text/remembername.txt').then(function(value){               
    console.log(value + ", " + name);

}).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The output is still the same - my name is bring printed first and the value of the Promise is then being printed on top/next to it.

Comment: @blueprintChris my output is this: 

`➜  Desktop node text.js
I will remember your name, , Chris
➜  Desktop node text.js
Howdy, , Chris
➜  Desktop node text.js
Hello there, , Chris
➜  Desktop node text.js
Nice to meet you , Chris
➜  Desktop node text.js
I will remember your name, , Chris
➜  Desktop node text.js
Thanks , Chris
➜  Desktop`

Comment: The file you pasted here and the code that you posted here, work with what I changed. Please check your code or file.

Comment: @blueprintChris Where is the code for logging "my name is chris"? I think some code is missing.

Comment: I edited and added more code, maybe it is to do with the function that the function call is within? I'm not sure.

Comment: The code I originally used was a working example to deduce whether it was the function or not... Now I have provided the full code which takes on board the MS bot framework and LUIS recognizer.

Comment: Any idea as to why mine is outputting like it is?